# An open set-valued version of path-connectedness

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

A topological space $(X,\tau)$ is **path-connected** if, for any two elements $x, y \in X$, there exists a continuous function $f_{x\to y}$ from the unit interval $\left[0,1\right]$ equipped with the Euclidean topology to $(X,\tau)$ such that $f_{x\to y}(0) = x$ and $f_{x\to y}(1) = y$.

Now suppose we were to define a variation on this idea that, instead of applying to points, applies to open sets of $\tau$ (let's call it "lane-connectedness"):

A topological space $(X,\tau)$ is **lane-connected** if, for any two open sets $U, V \in \tau$, there exists a [continuous set-valued map](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131206/what-is-the-definition-of-continuity-of-set-valued-functions) $f_{U\to V}$ from the unit interval $\left[0,1\right]$ equipped with the Euclidean topology to $(X,\tau)$ such that $f_{U\to V}(0) = U$ and $f_{U\to V}(1) = V$.

*What topological statements can be made about the idea of lane-connectedness?* I.e., is it equivalent to another form of connectedness, and if so, for which topological spaces?

As an example of an application; although the [solenoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid_(mathematics)) is neither locally connected nor path connected, I (perhaps erroneously) believe it is "lane-connected" as well as just connected.

Comment: What is the topology on the power set of $X$ that you are considering, or, at least, on the open sets of $X$? Please note that the Vietoris topology is defined on the $closed$ sets of a topological space.

Comment: And please specify whether you consider the complete power set or just the open sets, since the first might be path-connected, but the latter might be not (or vice versa).

Comment: To be clear on Ulli's point. $\tau$ defines continuity on functions into or out of $X$. But your "set-valued map $f_{U \to V}$" is a function into $\mathscr P(X)$, not into $X$ itself. Or possibly just into $\tau$ instead of all $\mathscr P(X)$. There is no automatic concept of continuity for such maps. You will have to choose a topology on the codomain of  $f_{U \to V}$ before you can talk about it being continuous.

Comment: I suspect that the Vietoris topology for the codomain of $f_{U\to V}$ is the "sensible" choice if $(X,\tau)$ is Hausdorff, which I'm happy to assume as well. (Compactness too, if that helps!) Also, if it doesn't cause problems, I'd like to consider the codomain of $f_{U\to V}$ to be (potentially) the entirety of $\mathcal{P}(X)$; I'm imagining that $f_{U\to V}$ is somewhat like the idea of a flow in dynamical systems theory.

Comment: What is your definition of the Vietoris topology on the *open* sets? (See my first comment.)